# How to tag different value range in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

(Solved)Say that I have a table:

```
+ ---+-----+------+
| id | Low | High |
+ ---+-----+------+
| 1  |   3 |   10 |
| 1  |   2 |    9 |
| 1  |  11 |   14 |
| 2  |   3 |   10 |
+ ---+-----+------+
```

How can I tag items with the same id and overlap value range with int(1,2,3,...)? In that case, the new table with tag would be:

```
+ ---+-----+------+-----+
| id | Low | High | tag |
+ ---+-----+------+-----+
| 1  |   3 |   10 | 1   |
| 1  |   2 |    9 | 1   |
| 1  |  11 |   14 | 2   |
| 2  |   3 |   10 | 1   |
+ ---+-----+------+-----+
```

since row2 and row1 have the same id and their value range has overlap, their tags are both 1, for row3 since its value range(low, high) is different from row1 and row2, its tag is 2. For row4, since it has a different id with above 3 rows, its tag will be 1.
the basic logic is: within the same id, we just need to distinguish all types of value ranges and give them tags(1,2,3...). we define two items' value range should be assigned the same tag if they have overlap. So the value range(3,9), (3,10), (2,9) are all tag 1 cuz they have overlap. for (11, 14) since its a completely different value range(with no overlap to any others ) so it is assigned a new tag The tag assignment is done distinctly for each id.
I am so confused, please help.

Comment: An alternative would be to simply subtract low from high, and output that number, what are you going to be using this number for?

Comment: I am just trying to assign a tag to these items with overlap value ranges, the tag assignment will be done distinctly for different id. There is no special usage for tag number.

Comment: Is this so you can order them by largest to smallest range? If so I can write a solution for you.

Comment: Hi @AlexZ one small thing to ask you: you do know you can vote up an answer(if it helped you in any way) and accept it if it is correct ? Thanks for your answer and feedback.

Comment: What if `(8,12)` is later added?  Then suddenly tags 1 and 2 need to be merged into a single tag?

Comment: @RickJames The given table is fixed, there will not later-added rows. If we do it in a recursive way, I guess the tag should be updated like all rows are tagged simultaneously.

Comment: @AlexZ I see you changed the accepted answer, did you find a dataset where my solution didn't work? Or did you simply prefer the explanation and/or syntax provided by the other answer?

Comment: @DerrickMoeller Hi Derrick, sorry I didn't realize there can be only 1 accepted answer so I accepted another one since that is also correct. Your answer perfectly solved my problem so I gave you the +50 bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to cluster your ranges per ID. Let's say the data for ID 1 is

```
+ ---+-----+------+
| id | Low | High |
+ ---+-----+------+
| 1  |   2 |    7 |
| 1  |   3 |    4 |
| 1  |   7 |    8 |
| 1  |   7 |   10 |
| 1  |  12 |   13 |
| 1  |  13 |   20 |
| 1  |  20 |   24 |
+ ---+-----+------+
```

We have two clusters: 2-10, 12-24. It doesn't suffice to look at one other row, say, the previous one, in order to decide whether they are in the same cluster. 3-4 and 7-8 may seem unrelated on first glance, but they belong to the same cluster, as they both overlap with 2-7.

I see an iterative process here where we order the rows by ID and Low and keep the highest range value as we move on:

```
+ ---+-----+------+---------+----------------------------------+
| id | Low | High | Highest | Cluster                          |
+ ---+-----+------+---------+----------------------------------+
| 1  |   2 |    7 |       7 | 1 (start with #1)                |
| 1  |   3 |    4 |       7 | 1 (3 <= 7)                       |
| 1  |   7 |    8 |       8 | 1 (7 <= 7)                       |
| 1  |   7 |   10 |      10 | 1 (7 <= 8)                       |
| 1  |  12 |   13 |      13 | 2 (next number, because 12 > 10) |
| 1  |  13 |   20 |      20 | 2 (13 <=  13)                    |
| 1  |  20 |   24 |      24 | 2 (20 <= 20                      |
+ ---+-----+------+---------+----------------------------------+
```

For an iterative process, we need a recursive query in SQL:

```
with recursive numbered as
(
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by low) as rn
  from mytable t
)
, cte (id, rn, low, high, highest, tag) as
(
  select id, rn, low, high, high, 1 from numbered where rn = 1
  union all
  select 
    n.id, n.rn, n.low, n.high, 
    case when n.low <= c.highest then greatest(n.high, c.highest) else n.high end,
    case when n.low <= c.highest then c.tag else c.tag + 1 end
  from cte c
  join numbered n on n.id = c.id and n.rn = c.rn + 1
)
select id, low, high, tag
from cte
order by id, low, high;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f38a60cdcbb2711e5fb1d7fd7fefa07

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to do this.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
    SELECT id, Low, High, Low AS MinLow
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.id, cte.Low, cte.High, yt.Low
    FROM cte
    INNER JOIN YourTable yt ON yt.id = cte.id AND cte.MinLow > yt.Low AND cte.MinLow <= yt.High
),
g AS
(
    SELECT id, Low, High, MIN(MinLow) AS MinLow
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY id, Low, High
)
SELECT id, Low, High, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION by id ORDER BY id, MinLow ASC) AS tag
FROM g
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for other data examples but with what I am given, this will work:

```
select id, low, high,
DENSE_RANK() over (partition by id order by id, res desc) as tag
from
(select id, low, high, (high-low) as res
from test) a
```

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=351c938ac49d4008d9100901fa89de5d)

Comment: High VBoka, thank you so much for you answer, but there is a problem here, so if I insert another row "insert into test values(1, 3, 9)" under the second row, this row should also have tag "1" since it has overlap with row 1 and row2, but instead it is tagged "2". In this case, I wan to give a new tag if and only if the row has a completely new value range(which means it has no value range overlap with all other rows with the same id).

Comment: I have changed my query(I have added order  by id in inner query) but ok I am confused. How do you mean that 1, 3, 9 would have a tag 1 ? The difference is 6(9-3) so it would be a tag 2 right?

Comment: I am analyzing and I am not following what you are talking about. You said that the tagging is done like this: ID and then range(low, high). 1,3,9 does not have the same range as 1,3,10. Or am I understanding this range in a wrong way?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusing description, the basic logic is: within the same id, we just need to distinguish all types of value ranges and give them tags(1,2,3...). we define two items' value range should be assigned same tag if they have overlap. So the value range(3,9), (3,10), (2,9) are all tag 1 cuz they have overlap. for (11, 14) since its a completely different value range(with no overlap to any others ) so it is assigned a new tag

Comment: I understand. Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas about that? Thank you so much.